# How to de-normalize text in Python?

Tags: python, text, nlp

I am currently working on a Python project using text semantic to match similarities. At the end, my goal is to have a dataset column where all my interesting words are in order to be searched in by a dumb searchbar.

Currently I have in a column my original text and my normalized text. Is there a way to create all denormalized forms of each word (or at least for each noun) ?

Answer (score 3):

I understand that you mean to generate all possible inflexions of an English word. For that, you may use [LemmInflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect) as follows:

```
from lemminflect import getAllInflections

> getInflection('watch', tag='VBD')
('watched',)

> getAllInflections('watch')
{'NN': ('watch',), 'NNS': ('watches', 'watch'), 'VB': ('watch',), 'VBD': ('watched',), 'VBG': ('watching',), 'VBZ': ('watches',),  'VBP': ('watch',)}
```

**Update:** for French, you can use [inflecteur](https://github.com/Achuttarsing/inflecteur):

```
from inflecteur import inflecteur
inflecteur = inflecteur()
inflecteur.load_dict()
inflecteur.get_word_form('pris')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't find a similar package to match with French words

Comment: I updated my answer with information for French

Comment: Unfortunately "inflecteur" doesn't work as "lemminflect". For example if I use it for the word "montre" (which is "watch") and it doesn't give me the plural form for example.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  Sorry, I'm not aware of any other inflection Python package for french.

Answer (score 0):

You can take extracted data (JSON lines) from Wiktionary from here: https://kaikki.org/dictionary/rawdata.html and look for the "forms" key for individual words. It basically contains the contents of the Wiktionary inflection tables. Depending on the language and Wiktionary edition the completeness will vary, sometimes articles will be included and sometimes you will need to remove some entries (stuff that appears in the table, but is not strictly an inflection).